# why is my master branch merging into another branch

Tags: github

this is my first day learning github and i tried to merge a branch to my master branch

so here's what's in my master branch (it's just a text file)

```
# test-repo2
-html
-css
-js

-angular

-django
```

and here's what's in my another branch

```
# test-repo2
-html
-css
-js
-react

-react hooks

-deno
```

so basically i want to replace the "django" and "angular" in master branch with "react"  "react hooks" and "deno" from another branch in other words i want to make the commit in master looks completely the same as the commit in another branch but i want to do it by merging the other branch to the master not the other way around not like [this](https://github.com/happdevcoder/test-repo2/network)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to merge your master branch into other branches as well as other branches into master.

You should choose the correct option while doing the merge. You should choose your other branch as source branch and master as target.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i did the correct option maybe is something to do with my other branch being 1 commit ahead of my master branch? what do you think?

Comment: i see there are some changes in your git repo. were you able to figure it out?

Comment: nope, not yet i just butchered the file i'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: im no expert, but i keep on trying it in github and it didn't work until i tried it with git remote and did the exact same thing and it finally worked  https://github.com/happyprogrammer-code/git-remotetesst-1/network